# DEBIAN 9 Encrypted home on separate disk acccess via SFTP with no login shell

Tags: debian, sftp, encryption

i have a Debian 9 server with /home on a separate disk.
There are mutiple users with sftp accounts, they all have no login shell to increase security, so plain sftp only.

Similar to this:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-sftp-without-shell-access-on-ubuntu-16-04

enhanced with: useradd $USER -s /sbin/nologin -M

Now i want to encrypt the complete /home/ folder (Multiple users with /home/$USER).
I am not quite sure if this will work?

When the user has no shell access, will the system decrypt the $USER folder correctly?

I do not want to blow my system.. any ideas?

i tought on:
 copy all data
 deluser(s) 
 adduser --encrypt-home 
 finally paste all data 
But SFTP wont login because it cant...dont want to shred my system

Comment: Depends on how you plan on encrypting.

Comment: ;) update in the last lines

Comment: Should work, if your SSH daemon is configured to use PAM.  Best way to find out if it'll work is to set it up on a scratch system.